# Why is my custom-button class not overriding the btn background color proptery

Tags: html, css, sass, bootstrap-5

I am using bootstrap5 variant-button mixin in order to create a button with custom color. I have successfully been able to change the default color of the hover effect, but I haven't been able to set the background color of the button. Based on the developer tools of the browser, seems like the background-color property of my custom class is not overriding the default btn's class background color.

#### My custom bootstrap scss code

```
@import "../bootstrap-5.0.2/scss/functions";
@import "../bootstrap-5.0.2/scss/variables";
@import "../bootstrap-5.0.2/scss/utilities";
@import "../bootstrap-5.0.2/scss/mixins";

$my-custom-color: #ffa500; /* orange */
.my-custom-button {
  @include button-variant($background: $my-custom-color, $border: $my-custom-color, $color: #fff, $hover-background: darken($my-custom-color, 10%));
}

@import "../bootstrap-5.0.2/scss/bootstrap";
```

#### My html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/bootstrap-custom.css" />

  <title>Navbar</title>
</head>

<body>
  <a class="btn my-custom-button">custom button</a>
  <script src="bootstrap-5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

#### My output

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xr2aJ.png)

I already tried overriding more button-variant mixin variables, but the result is still the same.

Comment: you are importing the full stack after importing parts, you just need the rest of the required parts you may be undoing your customization, see option B steps in the example https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/customize/sass/#importing

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$my-custom-color: #ffa500; /* orange */
.my-custom-button {
    @include button-variant($my-custom-color, darken($my-custom-color, 7.5%), darken($my-custom-color, 10%), lighten($my-custom-color,5%), lighten($my-custom-color, 10%), darken($my-custom-color,30%));
}

@import "../bootstrap-5.0.2/scss/bootstrap";
```

Or if you want Bootstrap to handle all the color variations, you can set the primary color itself:

```
$primary: #ffa500; /* orange */
$enable-shadows: true;
$prefix: "mo-";

@import "../bootstrap-5.0.2/scss/bootstrap";
```

See the docs here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/customize/sass/